# Mirror Function in Modeling

Tags: modeling, mirror

[image]

I am a beginner with Blender, I have the newest version of 2.9. I have been successful using mirroring in sculpting mode. However, I cannot get mirroring to work fully in low-poly modelling. It works with grab, extrude and scale tools, but not with others, such as loop-cut or poly-build tools. Is it something I am doing wrong, or the software currently doesn't support it?

For example, in the screenshot shown, I have made the extrusions from the cube successfully with the help of mirroring on Y axis turned on, and now trying to use loop-cut tool. But it does not repeat my loops on the other side.

Comment: Actually it did at the other side too. But the loop cut didn't changed the appearance at all.

Comment: If you switch to wireframe mode, it should be visible.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know if this function is in sculpting, but it is in the mirror modifier! In blender 2.79 in the modifier is a mirror, in the settings there is a function "Adjust edit cage to modifier result"
[image]

Enable all functions in the modifier window, and try different actions, watching your model!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Selected in red box! Try enable modifier mirror on your model, and search that function menu!